# How to use max and min of v-money, vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

Basically I want to define that the input v-money only accepts a maximum value 10,000 and a min 5,000
I'm fixing the rule but it works and it doesn't give me an error either
This way I use it:

```
<money v-model="packageForm.crime.theftDisappear" class="form-input input-lg" v-bind="config"></money>
<script>
export default {
 data() {
        return {
            config: {
               decimal: '.', 
               thousands: ',', 
               prefix: '$ ', 
               suffix: ' #', 
               precision: 0, 
               masked: 
               false, 
               min: 0, 
               max: 100
              },
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

with min and max, it didn't work for me, I did it through watch. my task was to limit to eight digits. I will give an example, it can be useful to someone:

```
<div id="app" class="empty">
    <input v-model="price" v-money="money" /> 
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 0,
      money: {
        decimal: ',',
        thousands: '  ',
        prefix: '',
        suffix: '  suffix',
        precision: 0,
        masked: true
      }
    }
  },
  watch:{
    price(p){
    p = parseInt(p.toString().replaceAll(/\D+/g, ''))
      if(p > 99999999){
        p = 99999999
      }
    }
  }
})
```